# What are some options for putting another, smaller copy of this long Latex item?

Tags: support, mathjax

I put a continued fraction at

[Solving Diophantine Equation - odd Periods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393247/solving-diophantine-equation-odd-periods/1394771#1394771)

which came out very well, that is exactly how I like to display these. I will leave that section in place regardless.

However, I would like to place a second image of the same thing below, in some way smaller, so that the entire calculation fits within the intended answer box and does not overlap the text on the right hand side (currently Hot Network Questions). I can think of: successfully make a landscape style jpeg and upload that?; somehow make the same Latex display in smaller font size?? For something much longer or more like a sequence of related equations, I would just split into two lines, which is what I did on paper at home when doing the calculations.

So that's the question, what are some ways to do this?

In the answer by quid, the size command \tiny is probably too small, and MSE refused the command \footnotesize (I checked, I spelled it correctly). I was pleasantly surprised to find the command \scriptsize just right for the purpose. I  repeated the final line in full size numbers but without big spacing, as a big part of the lesson is that, in Pell convergents for $\sqrt d,$ the value of $x^2 - d y^2$ also repeats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to control the size of the MathJax in the usual way, see ["sizing text"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts)

For illustration:

Original:
$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{5}{1} &  &  \frac{11}{2} & &  \frac{16}{3}  & & \frac{27}{5} & &  \frac{70}{13} & &   \frac{727}{135}  & &   \frac{1524}{283}  & &   \frac{2251}{418}   & &   \frac{3775}{701}  & &   \frac{9801}{1820}   & &   \frac{101785}{18901}  \\
              \\
-29 & 1 & & -4 &  &  5 & &  -5  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -5  & &   5   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

With `\small`

$$  
\small
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{5}{1} &  &  \frac{11}{2} & &  \frac{16}{3}  & & \frac{27}{5} & &  \frac{70}{13} & &   \frac{727}{135}  & &   \frac{1524}{283}  & &   \frac{2251}{418}   & &   \frac{3775}{701}  & &   \frac{9801}{1820}   & &   \frac{101785}{18901}  \\
              \\
-29 & 1 & & -4 &  &  5 & &  -5  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -5  & &   5   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

With `\tiny`

$$  
\tiny
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{5}{1} &  &  \frac{11}{2} & &  \frac{16}{3}  & & \frac{27}{5} & &  \frac{70}{13} & &   \frac{727}{135}  & &   \frac{1524}{283}  & &   \frac{2251}{418}   & &   \frac{3775}{701}  & &   \frac{9801}{1820}   & &   \frac{101785}{18901}  \\
              \\
-29 & 1 & & -4 &  &  5 & &  -5  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -5  & &   5   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

Comment: very nice, just the single word tiny. Let me try that

Comment: That worked. The small size appears below the end of Hot Network Questions in any case. Then the tiny fits in the intended window width. I finally repeated the line of $x^2 - d y^2$ values alone, to emphasize the periodic nature of those. On a side note, i think continued fractions are the cleanest way, given $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ to solve $Ax-By = 1,$ because the little 2 by 2 determinants are always $\pm 1.$ When I answer that way, however, it is never popular, and it is a good deal of work to typeset even that much. Oh, that is exactly how i wrote that task in my C++ programs.

Comment: Ahh. But on my tablet the `\tiny` still bleeds over the right margin. Not to mention that on my laptop I just set the "Scale All Math" option in the MathJax menu to 200%. It's all pretty big again (admittedly, the `\tiny` stuff is less big than `\small` or "Original", but it still bleeds over the right margin.) Boy, it's almost enough to make you think that taking steps to ensure that your MathJax appears exactly the way you intend it to everyone is a fool's errand.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, thanks for checking. The one thing that might work is to make a landscape option jpeg, a task that need have nothing to do with MSE or mathjax; I don't know much about mathjax and probably never will. Out of all the people putting effort into Latex and Beamer, especially the latter, someone has a way to do this; after all, Beamer slides seem to have landscape as the default...hmmm, the guy who gave me the Beamer outline I edited to become my own talk might know.

Comment: @ArthurFischer yes, personally, I thus try to avoid big blocks of MJ as much as possible.